# Is there any screenplay which is widely considered by screenwriters to be perfectly written?

Tags: dialogue, screenwriting, examples

Is there one Screenplay that is an example of being perfectly written by the majority of screenwriters that they keep at the ready to refer to while writing their own works?  I was hoping to learn of one example of words either written or an image to keep on my desktop.

Comment: If a writer ever tells you that a work is "perfectly written", either he wrote it himself and is suffering from Dunning-Kruger syndrome, or he's lying.

Comment: I don't know of a screenplay. But, there is a style considered optimal for commercial success (You are likely familiar). I heard about this recently - i think it was in Brandon Sanderson's youtube classes (BYU318, episode 3).  In short, the three-act structure derives from theater/film and has evolved to the point that the exact page for any of the formulaic devices has been sorted.

Comment: @F1Krazy Why limit yourself to either? Why not both? :)

Comment: @Doug6388, I edited the title of your question to try to better summarize what you're asking. That said, I fear this might be a bit too opinion-based for our format; however, I'm leaving that up to the community to decide. As for my edit, if you feel it changed your intent, then by all means go ahead and [Edit] further.

Comment: Maybe not *perfect*, but you might learn a lot by tracking down copies of winners of the Academy Of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences' Best Original Screenplay or Best Adapted Screenplay awards (commonly called "Oscars"). Those awards are voted on by members of the Academy who **must be screenwriters** to vote on best screenplay.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are many. You can find them quoted in scriptwriting textbooks.

For instance, Linda Seger in her famous book *Making a good script great* cites *The witness* by E. Wallace and W. Kelley as a paradigm of a good script.

Every book about scriptwriting contains many examples of "good scripts". There may not be a universal consensus, but those examples are what the teaching of the art is based.